# What is the meaning of the -scan within a hostname (in regards to OBIEE)?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, obiee

I want to connect my OBIEE to a table which is supposed to be within BI.

So what I do is examine the Connection properties inside of SQL Developer :

[image]

And I see that the hostname is "ed10-scan"  - is this some special notation for SQL Developer, or some kind of metadata? I was expecting  it say something something like "ed1001" or "ed2002" .

Answer (score 1):

A "hostname" is the logical name of a - in this case - server.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname

It can literally be anything one wants. if you "need a hostname with a number like..." then give your server a new name or at least a new alias over which it can be reached on your network.